# Conditional validation in angular ng messages

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I'm using ng messages module for my validation purpose, I have two input fields. I need to check whether both the input boxes have 0 as its value. It should not allow user to save form, if both the input fields have 0.

How can I achieve this using ng-messages module?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="text1" ng-model="text1">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="text2" ng-model="text2">
```

What I need is, invalidate the form if both of these text boxes have value as 0 at the same time.

Comment: could you show use, what you have tried so far?

Comment: Update code you tried that helps us to suggest

Comment: @PankajParkar I have added code now.